# Reading data off of an embedded viz table

Tags: rest, tableau-api

I am currently working on a project and came across a Tableau workbook that I would like to export to CSV, however I don't have the permissions to simply export the view to CSV. Does anyone have any experience working with any tables/visuals made using a viz API and have suggestions as to how I could "copy" the data into a CSV file? I was thinking of using a **scraper** but I have limited experience in doing so. Any help would be much appreciated.

The table for reference : https://public.tableau.com/views/ESReports-Tables/EnrolmentsOverview?%3Aembed=y&%3AshowVizHome=no&%3Adisplay_count=y&%3Adisplay_static_image=y&%3AbootstrapWhenNotified=true&%3Alanguage=en&:embed=y&:showVizHome=n&:apiID=host0#1

I have already tried contacting the admins themselves for a copy of the CSV to which they sent me a link to another table that was also not available as CSV (even though they claimed it was). In other words, they were no help.

Comment: Does this answer help get you started? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831517/python-selenium-webscraping-of-tableau-public-how-to-assign-favourites-to-workb

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!